# Picks Origin Cant Move Cube

Tags: modeling, mesh, origin

Absolute newbie here. Blender 3.6
To be used for 3d printing purposes.
I installed blender and watched a few videos. When I try to move the cube , it picks the origin instead. I have tried the drop down box and a few other methods that were suggested.

Uninstall and installed 3.3 and then 2.9. Still does them same thing.
Im come from SolidWorks background and when I first tried blender I might have rightclick a setting accidentaly.
But if I did wouldnt the reinstall cured it?
I have to run blender from a shortcut of the debug exe to prevent a startup crash.
Windows 10    16 Gig memory     Radeon HD 7570 video      1.3(?) 2 core i7 processor
Please help

Comment: Hello, maybe you have enabled the option called Transform Affect Only Origins on the top right of your 3D view? If it's not the case please show some screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option is disabled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you need to pick the right tool in this toolbar. If this toolbar isn't visible, hit <kbd>T</kbd>, or click *View* followed by *Toolbar* in the menu at the top of the 3D view.

[image: Toolbar]

If you hover your mouse over the tools, tooltips will be shown, explaining what the tool does. Those that have a corner arrow can be expanded, to select a subcategory. From top to bottom, the tools are:

Select Box - with this active, you can select an object by clicking it, or you can use you mouse to draw a box that selects several objects.

Cursor - This puts the 3D cursor where you click.

Move - This lets you move one or several objects, by dragging the mouse while holding the left mouse button.

Rotate - This lets you rotate one or several objects, by dragging the mouse while holding the left mouse button.

Scale - This lets you scale one or several objects, by dragging the mouse while holding the left mouse button.

Transform - This lets you transform one or several objects, by dragging the mouse while holding the left mouse button. This combines Move, Rotate and Scale, and what is done depends on where you click. Would probably need an answer of its own to explain fully.

Annotate - This lets you add annotations to your scene. I've never actually used it, but it looks like a grease pencil to me.

Measure - Lets you measure the distance between two points.

Add - Defaults to Add Cube, but by clicking the corner arrow, you can choose from a few other primitives to add.

Comment: Looks like Blender doesnt like my computer. Blender 2.9 runs on my other laptop but not this one. 2.9 or 3.6 will not run on this laptop. Its a HP Elitebook 8570p with 16gigs of memory, Windows 10/64, and a SSD hard drive. Is it just to old or bad drivers? Anything else? I like the size of this computer and would really like to use it.